# How to fetch the column contents based on the row number

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to fetch column contents based on the row number (I have written the code to get the specific row number of the clicked cell.. all I want to do is retrieve all the column contents of that particular row) in data grid view using c#.

Here is my Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  this.dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);

  this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit_1);

  this.comboBox1.Size = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size;

  this.comboBox1.Visible = true;

}


void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{

  this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

  this.comboBox1.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;

  this.comboBox1.Size = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size;
  this.comboBox1.Visible = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  int i;
  if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
  {

    //this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
      var value = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].RowIndex.ToString());
      MessageBox.Show(value); // right here i am getting the row number of clicked cell.
```

Comment: post your code. so that c#-super-heroes will not start form scratch.thanks

Comment: It's a **column** (not a *coloumn*)

Comment: What you tried? Post your code.

Comment: `I want to do is retrieve all the column contents of that particular row` Then why using combo box its confused explain clearly

Comment: basically i have a Data grid view.. and when i double click on any particular cell then combobox will appear on that particular cell and user can edit the value of that cell. Now the thing is i want to grab all the contents of that particular row which user has edited and want to copy the contents to the text file in the local device! Hope i have cleared your doubt satson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that you have a DataTable as the DataSource of dataGridView1**

The below code gives the content of a cell if you know the **row and column indices**:

```
string data = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows[ROWINDEX].ItemArray[COLUMNINDEX].ToString();
```

The below code gives the content of a cell if you know the **row index and the column name**:

```
string data = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Rows[ROWINDEX]["COLUMNNAME"].ToString();
```